# Equivalent parametric curves have the same length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

I'm having trouble proving that length is preserved under equivalent curves.

Equivalent curves are defined as such:

> Two non-closed piecewise smooth parametrized curves are equivalent $\phi : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi : [c, d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent if there exists a continuous, piecewise $C^1$, strictly monotonic function $\gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ such that $\gamma(a) = c$ and $\gamma(b) = d$ and $(\psi \circ \gamma
> )(t) = \phi(t)$ for all $t \in [a, b]$.

I'm trying to show that $\ell(\phi) = \ell(\psi)$. I know that $\ell(\phi) = \int_a^b \lVert(\phi)'(t)\rVert dt$ and that $\ell(\psi) = \int_a^b \lVert(\psi \circ \gamma)'(t)\rVert dt = \int_a^b \lVert(\psi'(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)\rVert dt$. But it seems as though I've hit a dead end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical detail: since $\psi$ is only *piecewise* $C^1$, you  need to break $[a,b]$ into subintervals on which it's $C^1$, and deal with the length of each piece. Let's pretend this has been done already. Then your computation can continue with 
$$\int_a^b \lVert(\psi'(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)\rVert \,dt = 
\int_a^b \lVert(\psi'(\gamma(t)) \rVert \gamma'(t) \,dt
$$
because $\gamma'(t)$ is a nonnegative scalar. Now change the variable $u=\gamma(t)$, and you get $\ell(\phi)$.